# How to update (retrieve / modify / post) wiki content

Tags: rest, wiki, ibm-connections

I actually would just like to update some wiki pages in IBM Connections programmatically. However, I can't really bring together the data I get from a GET command with the stuff that I should PUT according to the API description in a nice way.

So what I do is actually

```
GET .../wikis/basic/api/wiki/{wiki-label}/page/{page-label}/media?convertTo=html
```

to get the wiki page's html content, as using

```
GET .../wikis/basic/api/wiki/{wiki-label}/page/{page-label}/entry
```

will give me all the metadata and the summary of the page, but not the html content.

Then I modify the html content programmatically and would like to put it to the wiki page again. However, using

```
GET .../wikis/basic/api/wiki/{wiki-label}/page/{page-label}/entry
```

requires not only the html content (without the `<html>`, `<body>` and some other stuff) but also some metadata that would be avialable using the

```
GET ..../entry
```

command.

So yes, it is possible to manually modify everything to get it it to work. But is there some API available for receiving and posting, that better matches together so that I really only need to read, modify and post the content (without dealing with the format, meta information and other stuff)?

Comment: The api is documented here https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+6.0+API+Documentation

Comment: Although I've never worked with the IBM Connections Wiki, glancing at the documentation link @umeli provided I suspect you'll want to change your approach, e.g. ditch the GET command and instead get, change/edit, and update the Wiki page(s) via the Wiki API: 

Working with wiki pages: https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+5.5+API+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Working_with_wiki_pages_ic55&content=apicontent

Comment: A follow-up thought @nogenius, Understanding the "Atom entity" will be important but I did not see it well defined on just a cursory glance at the documentation. You may (or may not) have to consider "recursion", e.g. if you have to deal with page containers that can have children (akin to a folder structure - depending on the IBM Connections Wiki's implementation)